# Count categorical values in DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame only with Categorical Values

```
    Col1 | Col2| ... | ColM
Row
 1   X   |  Y  | ... |  X
 2   Z   |  X  | ... |  Y
 3   Y   |  Z  | ... |  X
 .
 .
 .
 N   X  |   Z  | ... | Z
```

I would like to count how many times each category appeared in database
So example result:

```
X - 100 times
Y - 30 times
Z = 210 times
```

Thank You for help

Comment: `df.stack().value_counts()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most performant option is to use `np.unique` with the `return_counts` flag set:

```
u, c = np.unique(df, return_counts=True)
pd.Series(c, index=u)
```

There's also `stack` and `value_counts`, which is much slower, but simple and intuitive:

```
df.stack().value_counts()
```

Comment: That's the answer, I was thinking about `value_counts()` but completely didn't think about `stack()`. Thank You!